# Убрать лишние пустые символы в c# string

Tags: c#

Вот имею вот такой код

```cs
char[] buff = new char[64];
reader.GetChars(0, 0, buff, 0, 64); //Example
Console.WriteLine(new string(buff).Length) //64
```

Мне нужен размер слова Example (7 Букв, а не 64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[] buf = new char[64];
string s = new string(buf, 0, (int)reader.GetChars(0, 0, buff, 0, buf.Length));
Console.WriteLine(s.Length)
```

Comment: Выглядит как магия, можете добавить пару предложений с описанием?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, он возвращает длину. Я об этом сразу догадался, но всё-таки в msdn проверил. Вроде совсем не магия. Ну кроме того, что я не стал переменную для длины заводить. Кстати, зря там размер массива захардкожен был - поправил.